# How to get objects in specific path using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
TABLE OBJECTS

ID     OBJECT
1      root/o1
2      root/o2
3      root/folder1/o3
4      root/folder1/o4
5      root/folder3/o5
6      root/folder2/folder3/file.txt
```

I need the following queries:

Get list of objects & folders in root, example results:

```
ID    name           type
-------------------------
1     root/o1        object
2     root/o2        object
-     root/folder1   folder
-     root/folder2   folder
-     root/folder3   folder
```

Another query: Get list of object in root/folder1.

---

### May thoughts about how to solve it:

- Maybe to use regexp_count and serach for `/` string... But I don't see exactly how to do it.
- If it is not possible, I think maybe to put the data in another way in the database using MySQL arrays.

For Example:

```
id    folders     object_name
-----------------------------
1     ['root']             o1
1     ['root','folder1]    o1
```

---

How to do it in MySQL 5.7? I am using MySQL 5.7. So I can use Array & JSON functions.

Comment: The root query would be possible with a bit of string manipulation pain.  But your general problem would be _much_ easier to solve if you normalized your data.  Instead of storing a path as a single row, you can store each _level_ in the path as a single row.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how many levels will be (unlimited)

Comment: It is probably not an issue to add more records.  But to deal with arbitrarily long paths is not the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

I found some regexp's that can help me to achieve that. If you any other idea, you can still post new answer:

- Regexp to get Root files:

  ```
      ^root\/[^\/]+$
  ```
- Regexp to get root folders:

  ```
      ^root\/[^\/\n]+\/
  ```
- Regexp to get folder 1 files:

  ```
      ^root\/folder1\/[^\/]+$
  ```
- Regexp to get folder 1 sub folders:

  ```
      ^root\/folder1\/[^\/\n]+\/
  ```

I can do `union`, and `distinct` to get the lists I want.

I am still searching what is the best way to store file tables data in MySQL. comments are welcome

Comment: maybe you can store xml physically and path in DB. what format the file is?